# How to erase a certain element from a shared_ptr to a vector of objects?

Tags: c++, class, vector, shared-ptr

I have created a member variable (in the class `Group`) that is a `shared_ptr` to a vector (called `members` that stores objects of type `User` (a different class). Here is the member variable definition (empty):

```
std::shared_ptr <std::vector<User>> members = std::make_shared<std::vector<User>>();
```

To eliminate a certain `User` object from the vector (`members`), I created a member function (`remove`) inside the class `Group`. It checks all the `User` objects inside the vector and, when encounters the one with the `a.URI` value that is looking for, it erases the object at that location in the vector.

```
void Group::remove(User a) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < members->size(); i++){
        if (a.URI == (*(members->begin()+i)).URI) members->erase(*(members->begin() + i));
    }
```

That is my `remove` function by now, but it doesn't work. I have checked different configurations but can`t make it work. Is there a problem with my function? How should this function be implemented (special rules for shared_ptr?)? Is there a better/optimal way?

I think no more code is needed here to solve my question. However, for those who want a MCV example, I tried to write one [here](https://ideone.com/e.js/JsOmok) (Ideone).

Comment: Your remove implementation skips elements. Best to use `std::remove` instead

Comment: How about `auto &vec = *members;` Then vec can be used as a regular vector. Please note that whatever manipulation you do, it ain't thread safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) expects an iterator as its argument, so change

```
members->erase(*(members->begin() + i))
```

to

```
members->erase(members->begin() + i)
```

Secondly, after the element being erased, when `i++` is evaluated, you will skip the next element or get out of the bound of the `vector`. You might change the loop to

```
for (auto i = 0; i < members->size(); ) {
    if (a.URI == (*(members->begin()+i)).URI) 
        members->erase(members->begin() + i);
    else
        i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked fine. And good advice, I didn't see that problem about boundary or next element skipping.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you declare the vector `members` as static member of the group class. I did it like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>    
using namespace std;

class User{
public:
    int URI;
    User(int a){
        URI = a;
    }
};

class Group {
public:
    static vector<User> members;
    void remove(User a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < members.size();){
            if (a.URI == (*(members.begin()+i)).URI) members.erase((members.begin() + i));
            else
                i++;
        }
    }
    Group(User a, User b, User c){
        members.push_back(a); 
        members.push_back(b);
        members.push_back(c);
    }
};

vector<User> Group::members;

int main() {
    User a(1), b(2), c(3);
    Group obj(a, b, c);

    obj.remove(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps.